# VMware Hard Disk is full, cannot start - what to do?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, disk-space-utilization

One of our hosts disks is full, and I don't want to delete anything - as there anything we can do so it starts again?

ESXi Shell

[image: terminal]

[image: vsphere]

Comment: It's all in the [documentation](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.server_configclassic.doc_41/esx_server_config/managing_storage/t_increase_vmfs_datastores.html), or [for vsphere client](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/5.5/com.vmware.vsphere.hostclient.doc/GUID-B0D89816-02E5-4C42-AAFC-19751800A284.html). It's not the newest doc, but it should give the idea.

Comment: @Lenniey what dictates whether to expand and existing extend or to add a new extent?

Comment: Nothing dictates anything. Do what you need and what suits your requirements. I - myself - like to have _one_ disk/partition/LV/zfs(pool/slice)/whatever for one guest. Of course you can have n disks with m splices/LVs/..., but, as I said - whatever suits you.

Comment: If you don't want to delete anything, then I think your next best option is to migrate at least one existing vmdk to another datastore.